# How to extract number from a text in SQL query

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with data such as -

```
01-Jan
02-Feb
03-Mar
04-Apr
05-May
```

I want to extract 01,02,03 from above column. How to do this in sql?

Answer (score 0):

String functions should be good enough here. You can just take the first two characters:

```
substr(mycol, 1, 2)
```

If the number of digits is not fixed, you could also use a regex to capture as many consecutive digits as possible at the beginning of the string:

```
regexp_substr(mycol, '^\d*')
```